# Is it possible to delete a flutter asset using another app, for example any file explorer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-assetimage

Flutter document says

> An asset is a file that is bundled and deployed with your app, and is accessible at runtime.

Is it possible for other apps to gain access to that asset folder, and delete any asset from there?
Eventually, they are just the files stored somewhere locally in the mobile's storage, so it is likely that is very possible, right?

I didn't try anything yet

Comment: No, other apps should not have direct access to your app's asset folder, and they cannot delete or modify the assets from there.